# UWP Issue on TreeView Loading - very long list

Tags: c#, uwp, entity-framework-core, treeview, loading

I have reviewed this article [Treeview Loading Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604326/treeview-loading-issue) but it does not solve my issue.
I have this structure:
Person
 - Visit

Visit is hierarchical so I can have:

```
Person
 - Visit 1
 - Visit 2
   - Visit 2.1
   - Visit 2.2
```

and there is no way to determine which is the structure.

I've defined 2 classes Person and Visit and Using EFCore I've mapped the DB.

The Person loading code is:

```
           var aList = await context.VVisitHierarchy
                .Where(a => a.CodPaz == _PazV.CodPaz && a.Parent == null)
                .OrderBy(b => b.CreationOrd).ThenBy(b => b.Data).ThenBy(b => b.CodPar)
                .ToListAsync();

            foreach (var item in aList)
            {
                MTreeViewVisit aMVisit = new MTreeViewVisit(item);
                Visits.Add(aMVisit);
                await aMVisit.LoadDataAsync();
            }
```

and then I load all visits:

```
    public async Task LoadDataAsync()
    {
        using (var context = new TitoDocContext())
        {
            var aList = await context.VVisitHierarchy
                .Where(a => a.CodPaz == _VisitH.CodPaz && a.Parent == _VisitH.CodPar)
                .OrderBy(b => b.CreationOrd).ThenBy(b => b.Data).ThenBy(b => b.CodPar)
                .ToListAsync();

            foreach (var item in aList)
            {
                MTreeViewVisit aMVisit = new MTreeViewVisit(item);
                Visits.Add(aMVisit);
                await aMVisit.LoadDataAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

What is perfect is that I see the tree loading incrementally, is very nice.
What is NOT nice is that when I have multiple levels when I try to expand a level below I get an untrapped error as the items has not been loaded (or this is my assumption). I assumed this being the case because for small data set it always work perfectly but when I have 1000 customers and 10.000 visits it deadlocks randomly.

I've read I can "wait to add the root element when is loaded" but how do I determine is loaded with all the async?
Also I need to have the root elements in the correct order (from the query) not in "speed of creation" so what can I do? Maybe I can create the root element without child and then add the child once the whole structure is loaded? but again how to wait for all and then signal the update?

Comment: and user will scroll all 1000 customers and 10k visits? **do not load all** do some paging

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: You can find tutorials for pagination online. Here is an example provided by Microsoft in their [Contoso University application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-3.1#add-paging-to-students-index). This example application is using EF Core and is running .NET Core 3.1.